# Double integral of a region.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Could someone help with the following question please:

[image]

For shape one I think it is just $ \int_{-1}^{1} \mathrm  \int_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{f(x,y)}\,\mathrm{d}xdy $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For shape 1 it would be:

$$\int_{-2}^{2} \mathrm  \int_{-2}^{2} \mathrm{f(x,y)}\,\mathrm{d}xdy - \int_{-1}^{1} \mathrm  \int_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{f(x,y)}\,\mathrm{d}xdy$$

Can you see why?  Can you see how to express the other two shapes in terms of multiple integrals?

**EDIT:**

For the interior of shape 2 the integral would be:

$$\int_{-1}^{0} \mathrm  \int_{-x-1}^{x+1} \mathrm{f(x,y)}\,dydx + \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm  \int_{x-1}^{-x+1} \mathrm{f(x,y)}\,dydx$$

**EDIT 2:**

For the third shape the limits need to be

Outside Circle: $-\sqrt{4-y^2} \leq x \sqrt{4-y^2}$, $-2\leq y \leq 2$

Inside Circle: $1- \sqrt{1-y^2} \leq x\leq 1+ \sqrt{1-y^2}$, $-1\leq y \leq 1$

Comment: Oh goodness, I needed shaded region. I considerd the "white" one. I am sorry, It is what you said indeed for q1!
For part 2 is not is the square [-1x1][-1x1] - [0x1][0x1] ?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, it isn't the smaller square - rather, it is the bigger square minus the smaller square - see my answer or Tpofofn's edit.

Comment: Thank you. 
is the shape 3 given by limits $-(4-y^2)^{1/2} ≤ x ≤ (4-y^2)^{1/2} , -2 ≤ y ≤ 2$ minus $-(2-y^2)^{1/2}≤ x ≤ (2-y^2)^{1/2} , -1 ≤ y ≤ 1$   ?

Comment: You have the right thought. See my second edit coming shortly....

Comment: Aaah right. I did overlook the fact that the small circle is not at the origin. Thank you very much! I was close though :)

Answer (score 0):

For shape 1 this is
$$\int^2_{-2}\int^2_{-2}f(x,y)\mbox{d}x\mbox{d}y-\int^1_{-1}\int^1_{-1}f(x,y)\mbox{d}x\mbox{d}y$$

Comment: I don't think that your solution for shape 2 is correct.  Note that although the shape is symmetrical, there is no indication that the function is.

Comment: @Tpofofn Right. I'll remove that. Thanks!